# Batch file failing to run under Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I wrote the following script on a Windows 7 machine and it runs fine:

```
@echo off
md "%cd%\_reversedFiles"

for %%a in (*.wav) do (
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
    for /F "delims=" %%i in ('ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags^=encoder -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 %%a 2^>^&1') do set "encoder=%%i"

    for /F "delims=" %%j in ('ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream^=codec_name -of default^=nw^=1:nk^=1 %%a 2^>^&1') do set "codec_name=%%j"

    ffmpeg -i %%a -af areverse -c:a !codec_name! "\_reversedFiles\%%~na.wav"
    bwfmetaedit "\_reversedFiles\%%a" -a --ISFT="!encoder!"
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

However, testing it in Windows 10 throws up the following error:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'file01.wav':
  Metadata:
    copyright       : 2020
    IENG            : Me
    ISBJ            : file01
    encoded_by      : Me
  Duration: 00:01:16.23, bitrate: 4608 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 96000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 4608 kb/s
\_reversedFiles\file01.wav: No such file or directory
2020-06-22 15:29:02 \_reversedFiles\file01.wav: File does not exist
```

I've tried running it with the executables (ffmpeg etc.) in both the system32 and local folder, with the same error.

For information - both Win7 & 10 are running on virtual machines, so I'm not sure if that will have an impact?  I know there is no difference running scripts between Windows versions so I can't understand why I'm getting 'No such file or directory'.

The script is correctly encoded in UTF-8.  Have I missed something obvious?

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess `"\_reversedFiles\…"` should read `".\_reversedFiles\…"` or just `"_reversedFiles\…"`…

Comment: Have you tried to give permission to everyone over the directory: right click -> properties -> secutiry -> edit -> add: then type 'Everyone'. This give access to everyone in the computer, maybe this could work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but no joy I'm afraid.  It something to do with the for loop/variable - I ran `for %a in (*.wav) do ffprobe '&a'` in the command line and produced the same error; whereas running the code without the loop/variables works...

Comment: …regarding the first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564630/batch-file-failing-to-run-under-windows-10#comment110642849_62564630), you did that on both lines `10` and `11`, did you Tom? Also are you sure that both `%%a` and `!codec_name!` will never need double-quoting?

Comment: Apologies for asking the super obvious question, but there _is_ a `_reversedFiles` folder in the same directory as the script and you **aren't** running the script as Administrator, right?

Comment: @SomethingDark, they at least tried to create it in the current directory on line `2`!

Comment: Thanks for all the comments; @aschipfl for my shame this was the correct solution but I failed to amend all the instances.  Probably time I went to go to bed...

Comment: Oh, and I've just noticed that you've apparently save your batch file as UTF-8, when I'd suggest generally OEM encoding, _especially if using it on [tag:windows-7]_.